# ASIHTTPRequest Send Data With Each Request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, asihttprequest

I have an array which includes URLs of JSON feeds. I am using ASIHTTPRequest to download the feed and process it. Each feed contains several JSON entries or objects. The `request` downloads the data and selects only one object and stores it.

The feeds URLs look like this: http:www.*****.com/id.json, where `id` is some string. After downloading the data and selecting the object, I'd like to store the id in a dictionary as a key that maps to a value of the object downloaded.

How can I pass that string with the request? So for example:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.tag = 3;
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Now in `requestFinished`, I can identify that request as follows: `if (request.tag == 3`. Along with `tag` of 3, I'd like to send the ID. So I can do something with it in `if (request.tag == 3)`. Is there some property where I can pass a string or any data along with a request?

Comment: Question is not clear for me.

Comment: Question edited. Please re-read now.

Comment: Question doesn't make sense!!!!!

Comment: Question edited.. Could you please stop down voting me? This is actually a great question its just really hard to explain it I am trying my best!

Comment: I think I addressed your scenario in my answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass your own dictionary of data in the `userInfo` property, which, like the `tag` property, can be read back on the request after receiving the response.

```
NSString* jsonId = @"1234";
request.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:jsonId forKey:@"id"];
```

See [documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#handling_success_and_failure_for_multiple_requests).

> If you need to handle success and failure on many different types of
>   request, you have several options:
>
> 1. If your requests are all of the same broad type, but you want to
>      distinguish between them, you can set the userInfo NSDictionary
>      property of each request with your own custom data that you can read
>      in your finished / failed delegate methods. For simpler cases, you can
>      set the request’s tag property instead. Both of these properties are
>      for your own use, and are not sent to the server.
> 2. If you need to handle success and failure in a completely
>      different way for each request, set a different setDidFinishSelector /
>      setDidFailSelector for each request

---

If you want to post data like a web page posts a form, you can use the ASIFormDataRequest subclass. It makes it very easy to send POST requests with strings you add individually:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"first_name"];
[request setPostValue:@"Copsey" forKey:@"last_name"];
```

See the [documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#sending_a_form_post_with_ASIFormDataRequest).

Comment: I am not posting data.. I edited the question please read again.. Thank you

Comment: Edited again.. Hopefully makes since now.

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I need. I have many requests, but they can be categorized into three types. Those of the same broad type, I want to distinguish between them. Thank you @nekno